# How To change my PC time while using proxy and syncing with new IP

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I want to web scribing some web site there for I use web share proxy , my problem is when I get new IP I want to set time zone my PC according new Ip to driver ( Chrome , Firefox ,Edge ). How I can do this ?

I try use this code

```
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Emulation.setTimezoneOverride', tz_params)
```

but not working when I check the result from this web site, (https://www.deviceinfo.me/)
the **System Time Zone** is different **Local Time Zone** I want to be same system time zone and local Time zone.